# Payment Gateway integration in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, payment-gateway, payment-processing

I am working with an application which needs payment gateway integration in which the customer can pay via visa card, master card or american express he has 3 options, so integrating with paypal is of no use in this case.

Has anyone faced this sort of problem before and can provide the useful solution or link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go and integrate PayPal sdk in your app - https://www.x.com/community/ppx/xspaces/mobile

Comment: but can i get the same functionality as asked above

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you implement it as in-app-purchase?

Comment: i dont want to implement this as an in- app purchase because apple will take some % of the pay which sucks and i want to implement multiple payment gateways so is their any solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a more flexible solution than one offering just 3 payment methods.

To help you make a proper choice of a payment gateway, ask your future provider the following questions:

- What currencies do you process? (if you're planning to go global, you need to process a multitude of currencies)
- What security level can you guarantee? (it's always better to choose a PCI DSS compliant payment gateway)
- How many integration types do you offer? (the more - the better, as convenience is key to winning customer trust)
- Do you have any chargeback / fraud prevention guarantee? (it's essential; some gateways provide such solutions which are already built it)
- Do you accept any alternative payment options? (some customers want to pay using their e-wallets or even BTC... such options are also worth considering)

These questions will guide you toward making a proper choice. Now let's talk about integration - as this is your primary concern.

To allow your customers pay via Android / iPhone mobile or website application - find a payment gateway providing SDK integration.